# Sort Dictionary(Of List(Of Integer),List(Of Integer)) by keys

Tags: vb.net

How Sort Dictionary(Of List(Of Integer),List(Of Integer)) by keys

```
Dim sortedL As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of List(Of Integer), List(Of Integer))) = dict2UzOsnova.ToList
sortedL.Sort(Function(firstPair As KeyValuePair(Of List(Of Integer), List(Of Integer)), nextPair As KeyValuePair(Of List(Of Integer), List(Of Integer))) _
    CInt(firstPair.Key.ElementAt(0).CompareTo(CInt(nextPair.Key.ElementAt(0)))))
```

This sorted only by first number in Keys(image is not from sortedL this refers to my dictionary name dict2UzOsnova in order to want to be sorted afterwards
[image]

Comment: Why not use a `SortedDictionary` in the first place?  You can provide your own object that implements `IComparer(Of List(Of Integer))` when you create it.

Comment: If you expect any help at all then you might try actually explaining what criteria you want to use to do the sorting.  Expecting us to work it out from that rabble is a bit much.

Answer (score 0):

Dim dict2UzOsnova As New Dictionary(Of List(Of Integer), List(Of Integer))
        Dim listKey1 As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {2, 8, 12, 13})
        Dim listValue1 As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {43, 51, 57, 59, 71, 200, 207, 211, 238})
        dict2UzOsnova.Add(listKey1, listValue1)

```
    Dim listKey2 As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {2, 5, 12, 13})
    Dim listValue2 As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {37, 76, 77, 86, 89, 104, 116, 190, 230})
    dict2UzOsnova.Add(listKey2, listValue2)

    Dim listKey3 As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {2, 5, 10, 12})
    Dim listValue3 As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {37, 56, 57, 66, 79, 100, 123, 178, 230})
    dict2UzOsnova.Add(listKey3, listValue3)

    Dim listKey4 As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {1, 2, 12, 13})
    Dim listValue4 As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {43, 50, 55, 61, 88, 105, 112, 178, 309})
    dict2UzOsnova.Add(listKey4, listValue4)
    ''etc... Now should be sorted by key(maybe over IComparer).
    ''After Sort my dictionary dict2UzOsnova  I need to get as pictured above right AFTER SORTED or under:
    '                    >key (0) (1) (2) (3)  >Value (0) (1)  (2) (3) (4) (5)  (6)  (7)  (8) 
    ' dict2UzOsnova (0)        1   2  12  13          43  50   55  61  88  105  112  178  309
    ' dict2UzOsnova (1)        2   5  10  12          37  56   57  66  79  100  123  178  230
    ' dict2UzOsnova (2)        2   5  12  13          37  76   77  86  89  104  116  190  230
    ' dict2UzOsnova (3)        2   8  12  13          43  51   57  59  71  200  207  211  238
```

Comment: can someone help how to sort dict2UzOsnova by Key Ascending !

Comment: @jmcilhinney,thanks, I managed to solve it. If someone is interested, I can set up a code.